# Show screen on first launch only in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Tweetbot and Clear show's on the first start of the app a small tutorial screen how the app works. The screen with the small tutorial only pops up on the first start up of the app (1 time)

How and with what can i make a similar thing? Can anyone push me in the right direction?

View i mean:

[image]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In your viewDidLoad:

```
if (![@"1" isEqualToString:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                                objectForKey:@"aValue"]]) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"1" forKey:@"aValue"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    //Action here

}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by: The '1' stands for how many times you would to see the action. You're just setting a string, if you change this to any string, including 2, 3 etc it'll still only fire once.

Comment: Still working perfect on iOS 9. In my case I used this for my splash screen. My troubles were, I was using the same view for my splash screen and my main nav, upon tapping my left menu view, it would present my splash again. Solved that by placing [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"" forKey:@"aValue"]; in my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. So it reset on app launch. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 53):

I'm assuming by Xcode you actually mean iOS.

What you need to do is use the `NSUserDefaults` class to store a flag indicating whether the user has seen the tutorial screen before.

When your app first loads (or at the point you want to decide whether or not to show the tutorial screen), do something like this:

```
if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"hasSeenTutorial"])
    [self displayTutorial];
```

This checks the saved NSUserDefaults for the current user for a value named "hasSeenTutorial", which won't exist yet.  Since it doesn't exist, it will call `displayTutorial`. `displayTutorial` refers to your method for creating the tutorial view.  You can figure out that part.

Then, once the user closes the tutorial screen:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"hasSeenTutorial"];
```

That value will be saved for your user profile, meaning the next time it checks it, it will be true, so `displayTutorial` won't be called.

Comment: You forgot too `synchronize`.

Comment: If you check the doc's, "this method is automatically invoked at periodic intervals" so it is unnecessary unless the program is about to exit or has some other phenomena prohibiting it's call

Answer (score 9):

Certainly, if we would like to tell user something about features after update (not only  app launched first time), the solution below could be suitable.

In your viewDidLoad:

```
NSString *currentBundleVersion = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
NSString *previousBundleVersion = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"PreviousBundleVersion"];

if (![currentBundleVersion isEqualToString:previousBundleVersion] ) {
     // Here you can initialize your introduction view and present it!
}
```

Once the user closes the intro:

```
NSString *currentBundleVersion = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];    
NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if (standardUserDefaults) {
    [standardUserDefaults setObject:currentBundleVersion forKey:@"PreviousBundleVersion"];
    [standardUserDefaults synchronize];
}
```

In this case app bundle version stored in your standardUserDefaults will be differ from current bundle version only after update and shown only once as well as at first launch.

Answer (score 3):

Initialise your user defaults with a BOOL, something called `instructionsSeen` (or whatever you want) and set it to `NO` in your App delegate's initialize method.. In your app, test this value and if it is `NO` display your tutorial screen. As part of showing and displaying this screen, set the `instructionsSeen` to `YES` and store it in your defaults.

This way the demo screen will only show on first launch, unless the user uninstalls and installs the app again.

You could also show the demo for a small number of launches (say 3). In this case, don't use `BOOL` use a number and increment it instead.

Answer (score 2):

Xamarin.iOS Version within AppDelegate:

```
UIStoryboard storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("Main", null);

        if (NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.BoolForKey ("hasSeenTutorial") == false) {
            UIViewController vc = storyboard.InstantiateViewController ("StartPageViewController");
            this.Window.RootViewController = vc;

        } else {
            UIViewController vc = storyboard.InstantiateViewController ("NonStartPageViewController");
            this.Window.RootViewController = vc;

        }

        this.Window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();
```

In my StartPageViewController, I have a button which sets NSUserDefaults to true, so the next time it runs, it will start off with the NonStartPageViewController:

```
partial void RegisterButton_TouchUpInside (UIButton sender)
    {
        NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetBool(true,"hasSeenTutorial");
        NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.Synchronize();
    }
```

Comment: Nice, but where would you place the code the checks the "hasSeenTutorial" in the AppDelegate? I don't manually instantiate the storyboard at all, it's done for me based on project settings.

Comment: Ok, nevermind. I put it into the FinishedLaunching() method and blanked out the "Main Interface" in project settings.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if (![defaults objectForKey:@"firstRun"]) {
    [defaults setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"firstRun"];
    [self displayTutorial];
}
```

Comment: @ChrisLoonam I modified the code to which saves the status in NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 0):

Swift version :

```
if !(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("seenTutorial")) {
            //Tutorial part
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "seenTutorial")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Everyone is making this more complex and vauge than it needs to be...  Simple complete solution.

In the ViewDidLoad:

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"FirstLoadKey"]) {
    self.imageView.hidden = YES;
}else{
    self.imageView.hidden = NO;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:YES forKey:@"FirstLoadKey"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
}
```

Comment: It is not an image view... See there is a ViewPager at bottom of screen 
☻☻☻☻.