# Add tutorial in the start of application

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show screen on first launch only in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450391/show-screen-on-first-launch-only-in-ios)

I need to add a tutorial for my application on the start up of my application, but I want to run it only for one time that it when the application runs for the first time. Being more precise , If some one install the app and run it, first the tutorial view should display, but after that no tutorial should be displayed even after at the start of the app launch.

I think I have conveyed my problem in understandable words. If something is not clear please ask me.

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 5):

```
 Try this,  

 BOOL isAlreadyUse=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"AlreadyUse"];

 if(isAlreadyUse==NO)


{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:YES forKey:@"AlreadyUse"];

   [self showtutorial];
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for doing this.

```
if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"firstLoad"])
{
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"firstLoad"];
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

   //show tutorial screen

}
else
{
   //main screen
}
```