# Issue with Recognizing First Time App Launch

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450391/show-screen-on-first-launch-only-in-ios) to show a little intro message once the app has been started for the very first time.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
...    
if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"hasSeenTutorial"]){
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"hasSeenTutorial"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [interface addHelpCards:nil];
    NSLog(@"-First Time-");
} else {
    NSLog(@"-Not First Time-");
}
...
}
```

Problem is ... it doesn't work. I am testing this on my device. As soon as I double tap to completely shutdown the app and then restart I get the "First Time" message again. Any idea on what's wrong with this approach? I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if it is not working, I will eat my leg.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // ...

    id _object = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"hasSeenTutorial"];

    if (_object == nil) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@(TRUE) forKey:@"hasSeenTutorial"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        NSLog(@"-First Time-");
    } else {

        NSLog(@"-Not First Time-");
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: you've got a typo in the if statement. This is a better answer. You can see the difference is valueForKey vs. boolForKey

Comment: Oh. I got it. The problem actually wasn't in the code I posted! For testing I used a "removeAll" function which also cleared my NSUserDefault data ... thanks for the patience. :)

Answer (score 3):

You're only setting `YES` for `hasSeenTutorial` if `hasSeenTutorial` is already `YES` (it's in the else).  Just move that (and the `synchronize`) up to the first part of the if

Comment: Yes, sounds good. I updated the code. However the issue persists. Hm.

Comment: I tried the exact code you had (except for the `[interface addHelpCards:nil];` line, and after first launch, I'm getting "Not First Time" in my logs.  Try adding `NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]);` and see what the value of `hasSeenTutorial` is after first launch...should be 1.  Also...are you shutting it down, or uninstalling and reinstalling through XCode? Not trying to insult your intelligence, just double checking ;)

Answer (score 3):

you should be setting the Bool value in the if and not in the else. Right now the bool value will never be set

Comment: Oh, that makes total sense! I updated the code accordingly. However I still have the same issue.