# Knowing the app. launc in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

The app. delegate has the method that gets invoked when the app launches. Pain is my app is not following MVC and I have to reset many text fields to empty when the app. launches(not concerned about first launch). These txt fields are not created in app delegate so i cannot set  them in app delegate (as the txt fields are not accessible). how can i know the app has launched in the new class to reset the fields . Is there any condition like

```
if(application.HasAppLaunced)
{
}
```

KIndly help

Comment: This is may help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450391/show-screen-on-first-launch-only-in-ios

Comment: Rather than stick a plaster on bad design, maybe you should reconsider your avoidance of MVC?

Answer (score 1):

You could register your view controller as an observer of event

```
UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
```

or

```
UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
```

in your view controller somewhere in `viewDidLoad`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(appEnteredBackground)
                                                name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                               object:nil];
```

and add this method to reset your fields, you can reset all fields here:

```
- (void)appEnteredBackground{
    [textField setText:@""];
}
```

don't forget to unregister your view controller, put this in some appropriate location:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
```

Comment: [textField setText:@""]; can be called in applicationDidEnterBackground

Comment: @Hemant: OP said, `"These txt fields are not created in app delegate"`

Comment: ohh i missed it..:)
Thanks ! Adil.

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand what are you asking for, but if the question is how to detect whather app is active you may use following condition:

```
[[UIAppication sharedApplication] applicationState] == UIAppicationStateActive
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary  *)launchOptions
{

// Reset your text fields here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.. You can call a method to empty the`textfields` using `NSNotificationCenter`

You can write the following line in `AppDelegate`.

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"EmptyFields" object:nil];
```

You can write the following line in `viewDidLoad` method.

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(setEmpty) name:@"EmptyFields" object:nil];
```

You can do `textfields` empty in the following method. You can write it in your `ViewController`.

```
- (void) setEmpty{
NSLog(@"Empty....");
}
```