# IOS swipable welcome screen

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Some iOS apps come with a welcome screen that allows you to swipe through several pages and then lets you use the app. Usually they include a page control at the bottom to show progress of viewing the pages.

Is there a popular or standard library that is providing this functionality?

[image]

See also:

- How to show a screen only on the first launch: [Show screen on first launch only in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450391/show-screen-on-first-launch-only-in-ios)
- Page view controller: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/PageViewControllers.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its quite simple,

1. Create a ViewController named `WelcomeScreenViewController`
2. Then setup `UIPageControl` and `UIScrollView` on the XIB, and load all the welcome images.
3. Handle `UIScrollView` delegate methods, and determine that you scrolled to the last page.
4. When you reach last page, hide the whole pagecontrol, and scrollview and show a Welcome Screen with Start option.
5. On touching start option, change the window.rootViewController to your actual Home screen. And too save in UserDefaults that you have shown the Welcome Screen.

Initially your `window.rootViewController` should be `WelcomeScreen` if you haven't shown it before.

The above should be the logic to implement what you are looking for.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

I assume many of these are just custom made.

However check JazzHands by IFTTT, a library built for such screens with keyframe animations

[JazzHands](https://github.com/IFTTT/JazzHands)