# Show Tutorial View on First App Opening Only

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to create an introduction/welcome screen that displays only during the first opening of an app. I've had some success with the help of user 'chroipahtz' [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450391/show-screen-on-first-launch-only-in-ios), but can only get a black view to appear instead of my welcome ViewController. Note: This black screen does dismiss to the rest of my app correctly, and the app runs without errors or warnings.

[screen shot of black screen](http://www.dev.purdueesc.org/iOS_App/EXPO/black.png)

I have the following code in the root view controller "viewDidLoad" method:

```
if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"hasSeenTutorial"])
{
    WelcomeViewController *welcomeController = [[WelcomeViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:welcomeController animated:YES];
}
else{    NSLog(@"Tutorial has been seen");}
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"hasSeenTutorial"];
```

which displays the introduction view on the first opening. I have created a View Controller in storyboard, and have assigned it the correct custom class in the identity inspector.

[screen shot of storyboard](http://www.dev.purdueesc.org/iOS_App/EXPO/storyboard.png)

I have included the header:

```
#import "WelcomeViewController.h"
```

Please provide guidance if you can as to why the Welcome View Controller interface isn't displaying the grey view with text I've outlined in storyboard.

Comment: you should check the WelcomeViewController identity in storyboard. it should be welcomeViewController as written @mikael code.

Comment: You're saying welcomeViewController is correct instead of WelcomeViewController? As you can see in my screenshots, the view is called WelcomeViewController... just double checking.

Comment: i cant see the identity in storyboard its hidden. below the custom class. click on it & give it a storyboard identifier (best is your class name). check it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to push another view in the event of "else". The below code is a bit more robust and makes use of storyboard. You must name the view controllers and the storyboard for this to work:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{    
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:@"hasSeenTutorial"]){
        UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"welcomeViewController"];
        self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
    } else {
        UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"nonWelcomeViewController"];
        self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
    }

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I copied the above code into the app delegate "- (BOOL)application:" portion and left storyboardWithName:@"Main" alone as my storyboard is Main.storyboard. I also changed 'welcomeViewController' to 'WelcomeViewController' and 'nonWelcomeViewController' to its appropriate view controller alternative by copying and pasting from the view controller headings (to prevent typos).                                     At runtime I get the error "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException" implying that an IB connection is broken. Any recommendations?

Comment: `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"welcomeViewController"` refers to the storyboard ID that you can set in the identity inspector directly in storyboard not the class name.

Comment: This code was successful once I added:  [standardUserDefaults synchronize];      Thanks!

Comment: @Mika - Old thread, I know. But how would you go back to nonWelcomeViewController from welcomeViewController? More or less, within the welcomeViewController class, what code will go inside the "Close Tutorial" button to bring the view back to nonWelcomeViewController?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about making ContainerViewController like this

```
@interface ContainerViewController ()

@property (nonatomic) MainViewController *mainViewController
@property (nonatomic) TutorialViewController *tutorialViewController

@end

@implementation ContainerViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];

    _mainViewController = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self addChildViewController:_mainViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:_mainViewController.view];
    [_mainViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"hasSeenTutorial"])
    {
        [self showTutorialViewController];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"hasSeenTutorial"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
}

- (void)showTutorialViewController
{
    if (!_tutorialViewController) {
        _tutorialViewController = [[TutorialViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    }

    [self addChildViewController:_tutorialViewController];

    CGRect screenBounds = _mainViewController.view.bounds;
    CGRect fromFrame = CGRectMake(0.0f, screenBounds.size.height, screenBounds.size.width, screenBounds.size.height);
    CGRect toFrame = screenBounds;

    _tutorialViewController.view.frame = fromFrame;
    [self.view addSubview:_tutorialViewController.view];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{
                         _tutorialViewController.view.frame = toFrame;
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [_tutorialViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
                     }];
}
```

Please see [Apple's document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html) about "ContainerViewController".

And you can use my library which can count the number of launch.
See [this](https://github.com/ryufloat/TMLaunchCountManager) and try if you want. As it happens, I make it yesterday.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I removed the double '::' from the first [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] line.      I also received 'Semantic Issue: Missing '[' at start of message send expression at: "[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];" The alert carrot points to the second '[' bracket. Advice to remedy?

Comment: I'm sorry, `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey::@"hasSeenTutorial"]` this line has two bugs. **FIRST** you indicated on your comment, "::", this should be changed to ":". **SECOND** you must add the semicolon on the end of line.  Please fix these two bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You have set in storyboard, that some view controller in it is WelcomeViewController. But this doesn't apply in the opposite direction. When you initialise WelcomeViewController like you did, you have only instance of the class, that is not connected to the view controller in you storyboard.

What you have to do is to instantiate view controller from the storyboard like this:

```
UIStoryboard *storybrd = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"YourStoryBoardName"                 bundle:nil];
UIViewController *mycontroller =[storybrd instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"identOfWelcomeViewController"];
```

Of course you have to set proper identificator to the view controller in the storyboard.