# Navigation controller after Tutorial with Pageviewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I'm using a pageViewController to present all the feature of my app. However I just want to display it on the first start of the app and not everytime. In order to, I've created an object which store a boolean to display or not tutorial. This Boolean is used in AppDelegate.m

```
if(tutoStatus == NO)
    {

        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];

        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

        UIViewController *tutoViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];

        UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:tutoViewController];

        [self.window setRootViewController:navController];

        [Tutorial setTutoStatus:YES];
        [Tutorial savePrefs];
    }

    else
    {
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];

        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

        UIViewController *homeViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homeViewController"];

        UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:homeViewController];

        [self.window setRootViewController:navController];
    }
```

My problem is that I create a navigation controller in both of case. So, if I've got the tutorial to display, the user will get a back button in nav bar and can be back on the PageViewController. What is the best way to display the tutorial at the start of the app ?

Thanks

--EDIT

I solved my problem using the code below

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"])
    {
        NSLog(@"not first launch");

        UIStoryboard* storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                                      bundle:nil];
        self.homeViewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.self.homeViewController;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"first launch");
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        UIStoryboard* storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                                             bundle:nil];
        self.tutoViewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TutoViewController"];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.tutoViewController;
    }

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the Navigation Controller of the UIpageViewController & present the PageViewController modally by calling `presentViewController:animated:completion:`

Also, you might want to use **NSUserDefaults** to store the bool if you want to display the tutorial only on the initial launch of the app.

Something like in this link -> [Show screen on first launch only in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450391/show-screen-on-first-launch-only-in-ios)

Comment: I don't get it, I just deleted the navigation controller of the UIPageViewsController and try to present it, but it doesn't work.

`UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
        
        UIViewController *tutoViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
        
        [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:tutoViewController animated:YES completion:nil];`

Comment: What's the rootviewcontroller here?

Comment: `self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];
    
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    
    UIViewController *homeViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];
    
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:homeViewController];
    
    [self.window setRootViewController:navController];
    
    if(tutoStatus == NO)
    {
         //Here the code in the previous comment
    }`

Comment: Should you not be calling `[navController presentViewController:tutoViewController animated:YES completion:nil];` ? maybe with animated:NO?

Comment: I've found a solution, see my post I wrote an update.

Answer (score 1):

In the `viewWillAppear:` method of the view controller for the tutorial, you can use this to hide the back button:

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];
```

And then in `viewDidDisappear:`, you can restore the back button:

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:NO animated:YES];
```