# Making a screen which only appears once and never comes again

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I was wondering if there was a way in which a sort of how-to use the app guide would come up and show how to use the app the first time and when the person closes guide it never comes again.

Like some apps have a start image that show how to use the app. I want to make this and when the person closes the image, I want this image to never come again. Even after the app closes.

I use storyboards so I don't need to make this programatically, but I can. Can someone please write the code or tell me how to do this?

Comment: Have you searched for a solution / done any research?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show screen on first launch only in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450391/show-screen-on-first-launch-only-in-ios)

Answer (score 1):

Look into saving a BOOL to `NSUserDefaults` and checking that BOOL to see if the tutorial/intro screen has been presented before on launch (or wherever you want to show the one-time view).

Here's a link to the docs:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsuserdefaults_class/reference/reference.html