# Show Tutorial View on first time only

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to create an tutorial screen that displays only during the first opening of an app. i know i should use user defaults but how and where ? in method viewDidLoad or on app delegate class ?

Comment: Please use appDidFinishLauncing for this issue as per my view. Look at this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450391/show-screen-on-first-launch-only-in-ios  same question

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
- (BOOL)isAppAlreadyLaunchedOnce {
    BOOL isRememberMe = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"isAppAlreadyLaunchedOnce"];
    if (isRememberMe) {
        return YES;
    }
    else{
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"isAppAlreadyLaunchedOnce"];
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: where i should call a function ?

Comment: when your tutorial is finish after you store value like this     
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"isAppAlreadyLaunchedOnce"]; after check in appdelegate to tutorial is first time or another time

Answer (score 1):

Store the status whether the **Tutorial View** is displayed or not in `NSUserDefaults`.

If you want to decide at startup to show or not show the **Tutorial View** you should do it in **App Delegate** `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"shouldShowTutorial"])

//show tutorial

}
else{

//don't show tutorial

}
```

On the first time when the **Tutorial View** has been displayed set a flag in `NSUserDefaults`.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"shouldShowTutorial"];
```

Answer (score 0):

@Maddy has given correct answer but let me just clarify one thing why we will not use **viewDidLoad**?
Why we are using **didFinishLaunch**

### **in short:**

**viewDidLoad**

System has already decided which View to load when application launches .By default it's the **"Main"** storyboard's **initial view controller**

**didFinishLaunch**

System has done all tasks to show your app but has not decided which view to load. Thats why you can control here to show your tutorial screen first. :)